# Remove regulation tag while we still can?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I would suggest to remove/block the [regulation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulation) tag while we still can; would it be possible to have a notification or something if the asker selects `regulation` indicating he should specify either `faa` or `easa` or any other appropriate authority?

Related to [this question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-should-we-handle-country-specific-questions-answers), this is more about the current 'regulation' tag which is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: It would help if you could specifically delineate the problems that you see with the regulation tag so we know how to address your concerns.

Comment: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/177/if-i-have-a-float-plane-can-i-land-on-any-body-of-water Asks for regulations concerning landing on water; it's impossible to answer without knowledge of which jurisdiction is intended. Regulations are, by definition, bound to the jurisdiction they apply to, so I guess I'm kind of hoping the asker will get an extra nudge to specify it. Or create tags such as `regulations-faa`, `regulations-easa` to have them show up as autocompletions.

Comment: would FAR be a synonym for [tag:regulations-faa]?

Comment: @egid: FAR is an acronym for Federal Aviation Regulations (which are indeed the FAA regulations).

Comment: I know that :) I meant, in SE:Aviation, should it be set up as a tag synonym for 'regulations-faa', or should it stand on its own?

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/130/when-should-faa-vs-far-and-other-regulatory-tags-be-used

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the point that "regulations" is meaningless by itself but I'm not sure what the alternative is. I tried to find other Stack sites that might have similar issues with regions and countries:

- Politics [uses country tags](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-should-we-tag-country-specific-questions)
- Money also uses country tags, and decided that [they are useful](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/do-401k-questions-all-need-the-united-states-tag) even when the question itself is obviously referring to only one country
- English language is [discussing](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=country%20tag) a 'culture' tag but there seems to be no final decision yet
- Spanish language has settled on [country tags](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/how-should-we-tag-questions-on-regional-dialects-of-spanish) too, and considers 'standard' Spanish to be [a default requiring no tag](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/how-should-we-tag-questions-on-regional-dialects-of-spanish)

In aviation terms, that suggests the following ideas (hopefully there are more):

- Use country tags
- Use regulatory authority tags (FAA, EASA)
- Consider US/FAA a default that requires no tag

I find country tags quite attractive, because they can apply to more than just regulatory questions and would be useful for questions about common practices too: if the tag "US" is present, it would imply FAA/FAR/AIM etc. It also allows for the case where local rules take precedence (if such cases exist), e.g. if the UK has local aviation regulations that apply only in the UK, independent of EASA. If someone really wants to ask about EASA and not about one specific country then they can still tag it "EASA" instead of "UK", of course.

Authority tags seem more specific, but it's early days and although all the questions so far seem to fall into US (FAA) or Europe (EASA), the rest of the world exists too and there are numerous "CAA" authorities out there. Would we have "CAA-Singapore", "CAA-SouthAfrica" etc.?

I don't like the idea of treating the US as a default at all, simply because it promotes a US focus that might drive other decisions to the detriment of making this a globally useful site.

Comment: I like the idea of country tags, but I'd prefer to not treat US/FAA as default. If anything should be treated as default, then how about ICAO recommendations? Your last statement is actually my primary motivation, with only a few questions, a US-only culture is brewing (not saying it's intentional).

Comment: So this is the most popular answer, but there are now 22 questions tagged "regulation" so the problem is getting worse, probably because people see the other questions already tagged as such.  Most of the other questions seem to be falling under authority tags, and I think that it should probably be our "standard", applying country specific tags only when appropriate.

Comment: That sounds fine to me for now: using agency names makes sense and we can deal with finer distinctions using country tags if required. If we have ever so many questions about aviation outside the US and Europe that we need to do something 'smarter', well, that's a good problem to have :-) As for the regulation tag itself, it's still early days for this site and apparently people find the tag useful (or at least 'obvious') right now. If it does become a bigger issue in the future then we always have the option of organizing a tag cleanup, as other Stack sites have done.

Comment: Well, I think that most people are using that tag because a) they see it on other questions, and b) because it exists. The tag is not really useful without another tag that already implies regulation (like icao, FAA, far, etc.) so I think that we should get rid of it now before it requires a major tag cleanup.  Also, the suggested tags in this question: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/130/when-should-faa-vs-far-and-other-regulatory-tags-be-used would eliminate any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonable proposal. I'm not sure about the automatic prompt, but it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The questions using the tag have all been retagged as [faa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations), [easa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easa-regulations), etc. and it is now blacklisted so that it can't be used again.