# How should we tag questions about Canadian regulations?

Tags: discussion

For national regulatory authorities, we seem to have [settled on two tags](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/when-should-faa-vs-far-and-other-regulatory-tags-be-used). Using FAA as an example, they are:

- [faa](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa) - questions about the FAA as an organization, entity or jurisdiction
- [faa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations) - questions about US aviation regulations

This approach is also reflected in [easa](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easa), [easa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easa-regulations) and [caa-uk-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caa-uk-regulations).

How should we handle Canada? So far it looks like we're only using the [transport-canada](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport-canada) tag but by analogy with the FAA, we should use [transport-canada-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport-canada-regulations) instead. However, the tag would then have 29 characters, which exceeds [the 25 character limit for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain).

AFAIK there's no official or common abbreviation for Transport Canada, so it isn't immediately obvious how to shorten it in an understandable way. Assuming that we want to be consistent and reserve [transport-canada](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport-canada) for questions about the organization itself, then some ideas for regulations would be:

- [canada-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada-regulations)
- [transport-canada-regs](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport-canada-regs)
- others?

Or, we could decide that consistency isn't essential and we just use [transport-canada](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport-canada) for all questions about the organization *and* the regulations.

What seems like the best option here?

Comment: Ah, the Canadians!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use [tcca-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcca-regulations), since according to their [website](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/menu.htm), the National Aviation Authority in Canada is:

> the Civil Aviation Directorate, also known as Transport Canada Civil
>   Aviation (TCCA)